# Metadata mismatch problems - Angular

Tags: json, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I am getting the usual error:

> ERROR in Error: Metadata version mismatch for module C:/.../node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/index.d.ts, found version
>    4, expected 3, resolving symbol AppModule in C:/.../app.module.ts, ...

I have looked at other posts on here with regards to version differences in the `package.json` file, however I am unsure which is causing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see from the github page that bootstrap expects angular version 5.0.2 and you are using 4.2.4. So probably upgrading to angular 5 will solve your issue.

https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/package.json

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Vlad - Although it did open up another can of worms with regards to Typescript and it not liking the types I had put in :-(